# Google Drive - Shared Drive Permissions

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I was using an App Script Project to automate the creation of some accounts and profiles inside of our organization. I had been using this same method for adding the "Viewer" permission for the user I would like on the designated shared drive.

```
DriveApp.getFolderById("My_Dr!v3").addViewer(email);
```

However, within the past couple days, I suddenly do not have access.
[image: Drive App Error Message]

Like I stated before, I had been using this method and service for a decent bit of time but at the beginning of this week noticed this error. I have the service attached to the App Script project and have the Drive API enabled within the Google Cloud Project that is the container for App Scripts. Would there potentially be a setting that someone might have changed that is causing this? Anyone else have a similar experience to this?

*I do have the OAuth2 Service enabled within the App Script project if that affects anything*

**Reference**

Google Drive Folder Doc - https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder

Google DriveApp Doc -  https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is the type of access level you have in the shared drive.

The `Content manager` access level is not enough to perform this type of action as I was able to reproduce the exact same error message from the screenshot provided:

[image]

However, if I change myself as a `Manager`, which is the highest access level I no longer get the error message:

[image]

##### References:

- [Shared drives access levels](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7337554)

Comment: Makes sense, just makes me feel like I am losing my mind lol. Around 3 weeks ago I was able to call that method without being a member of the Shared Drive at all. On June 23rd, I had a new user onboarded, and he was added to a member of the shared drive through the App Script. I know for sure (99.99%) it was from the automation because we normally give users "Content Manager" access and this particular user still only has "Contributor" access to the shared drive now.